Angular Directive: Preventing Click Events from Being Treated as Drag Events
I'm facing an issue with an Angular directive where click events are mistakenly being treated as drag events. I've implemented a custom directive for drag scrolling functionality, but it seems that whenever I click on the scrollable element, it adds the 'dragging' class to the element as well as emits and the event, which triggers unwanted behavior.
import {
    Output,
    Directive,
    Renderer2,
    ElementRef,
    HostListener,
    EventEmitter
} from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
    selector: '[dragScroll]'
})
export class DragScrollDirective {
    constructor(
        private _renderer: Renderer2,
        private _elementRef: ElementRef<HTMLElement>
    ) {}

    private startX: number = 0;
    private startScrollLeft: number = 0;
    private isDragInProgress: boolean = false;

    @Output() onDragScrolling: EventEmitter<boolean> = new EventEmitter<boolean>();

    /**
     * *Handles the mouse down event to initiate drag scrolling
     *
     * @param event - The MouseEvent object
     *
     * @date 06 April 2024
     */
    @HostListener('mousedown', ['$event'])
    public onMouseDown(event: MouseEvent): void {
        //Emit event indicating the start of drag scrolling
        this.onDragScrolling.emit(true);

        //Set flag to indicate drag scrolling is in progress
        this.isDragInProgress = true;

        //Store initial scroll position and mouse position
        this.startScrollLeft = this._elementRef.nativeElement.scrollLeft;
        this.startX = event.pageX;

        //Add class to indicate dragging state (for styling)
        this._renderer.addClass(this._elementRef.nativeElement, 'dragging');
    }

    /**
     * *Handles the mouse up event to end drag scrolling
     *
     * @date 06 April 2024
     * @developer Rahul Kundu
     */
    @HostListener('document:mouseup')
    public onMouseUp(): void {
        //If drag scrolling is not in progress, do nothing
        if (!this.isDragInProgress) return;

        //Reset drag scrolling flag
        this.isDragInProgress = false;

        //Remove class indicating dragging state
        this._renderer.removeClass(this._elementRef.nativeElement, 'dragging');

        //Emit event indicating the end of drag scrolling
        this.onDragScrolling.emit(false);
    }

    /**
     * *Handles the mouse move event to scroll the container
     *
     * @param event - The MouseEvent object
     *
     * @date 06 April 2024
     */
    @HostListener('document:mousemove', ['$event'])
    public onMouseMove(event: MouseEvent): void {
        try {
            //If drag scrolling is not in progress, do nothing
            if (!this.isDragInProgress) return;

            //Prevent default behavior (e.g., text selection)
            event.preventDefault();

            //Calculate the horizontal movement of the mouse
            const movementX = event.pageX - this.startX;

            //Update the scroll position with smooth scrolling
            this._elementRef.nativeElement.scrollLeft = this.startScrollLeft - movementX;
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('An error occurred in onMouseMove:', error);
        }
    }

    /**
     * *Handles the wheel event to adjust the scroll position
     *
     * @param event - The WheelEvent object
     *
     * @date 06 April 2024
     */
    @HostListener('wheel', ['$event'])
    public onWheel(event: WheelEvent): void {
        //Define scroll speed based on wheel delta
        const scrollSpeed = 5;

        //Adjust the scroll position based on wheel movement
        this._elementRef.nativeElement.scrollLeft += event.deltaY * scrollSpeed;
    }
}



You can add multiple @HostListener()'s to a single function, you can then use event.type to get the type of event that is being executed and if it isn't the event you want, stop it from doing the rest of the function.
